# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apidjangowithjwt.emailservice'

Tags: python, django, django-views

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Ouc.png) of my project where apidjangowithjwt is the project name & emailservice and user are the apps.

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwYx0.png) in user app where I am importing emailservice app which is giving the error

Detailed error:
 File "F:\DjangoDemo\JWTAuthentication\apidjangowithjwt\user\views.py", line 17, in 
    from apidjangowithjwt.emailservice.views import send_email
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apidjangowithjwt.emailservice'

```
from apidjangowithjwt.emailservice.views import send_email **#giving error**
```

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hFDA.png) in emailservice app where I defined a function send_mail.

```
from django.core import mail

def send_email(**kwargs):
    with mail.get_connection() as connection:
        email=mail.EmailMessage(kwargs['subject'],kwargs['body'],kwargs['from_email'],kwargs['to_email'],kwargs['bcc'],
                                connection,kwargs['attachments'],kwargs['header'],kwargs['bcc'],kwargs['reply_to'])
        email.send()
```

I have also registerd my both apps in settings.py as:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'user',
    'rest_framework',
    'emailservice'
]
```

Comment: Try a relative import: `from ..emailservice.views import send_email`

Comment: You are missing the **`__init__.py`** file in the **`apidjangowithjwt`** directory. Create a empty `__init__.py` file inside the `apidjangowithjwt` will solve the issue

Comment: Relative imports will fail (those only work within a same package), and you DONT want to make your project a package (this is not necessary and could lead to "double import trap" issues). The proper solution is quite simply to use the correct qualified path for the import, which is `from emailservice.views import send_email`.

Comment: If I use ```from ..emailservice.views import send_email``` then getting different errorFile "F:\DjangoDemo\JWTAuthentication\apidjangowithjwt\user\views.py", line 17, in <module> from ..emailservice.views import send_email ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package –

Comment: I have created  ```__init__.py```  in apidjangowithjwt but still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

After trying lot of things,this worked for me.

`from emailservice.views import send_email`